# Elmah.Contrib.WebApi is not logging the routing exceptions for Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, elmah

I am using Web API 2.1 and trying to log all unhandled exceptions using ELMAH. I am trying to log errors for the following cases:

1. Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
2. Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
3. Exceptions thrown during routing.
4. Exceptions thrown during response content serialization .

I followed the below mentioned links to log all unhandled exceptions.
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/03/Getting-ELMAH-to-catch-ALL-unhandled-exceptions-in-Web-API-21.aspx

http://blog.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-web-api/

I have a controller :

TestController.cs

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        private IMessageProvider _messageProvider;
        private INewMessageProvider _newMessageProvider;
        public TestController(IMessageProvider messageProvider, INewMessageProvider newMessageProvider)
        {
            _messageProvider = messageProvider;
            _newMessageProvider = newMessageProvider;
        }


        public object Get()
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,"Error in processing the webapi");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        **[Route("api/test/{namee}")]**
        public HttpResponseMessage GetNewMessageByName(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,"Name parameter cannot be empty");
            }

            //int i = 1, j = 0;

            //int k = i / j;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _newMessageProvider.GetNewMessage() + name);
        }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
using Elmah.Contrib.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

namespace DemoStructureMapWebAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services



            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());


        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to test the route : http://localhost:62145/api/test/testnewname
and I am seeing the below error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:62145/api/test/testnewname'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Test' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

There is a mismatch in the route parameter: namee (i.e **api/test/{namee}**) and the input parameter to the method **GetNewMessageByName(string name)**
Hence I am getting the error but I see that error is not logged by ELMAH. I am not able to see the error in the ELMAH logs.
As per the articles mentioned above it seems that Elmah.Contrib.WebApi nuget package has fixed the issues.

I am not sure if I am missing something else.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

it turns out that 404 errors are treated a bit differently in Web API, they bypass the usual request pipeline and are sent directly to the browser before ELMAH knows anything about them.

So in order to log 404 errors with ELMAH you need to add a 'catch all' route as the last route in your WebApiConfig to log the errors manually.

I've just updated my blog post and included a working example solution that will catch all errors including 404s - http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/03/Getting-ELMAH-to-catch-ALL-unhandled-exceptions-in-Web-API-21.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is very helpful :)